Compute: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{n(2n+1)}$
I did partial fractions and deconstructed the sum and ended up with the following results:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{n(2n+1)}=4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{2n+1}$$
$$=4\left(1-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{7}+...\right)=4\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-2}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1-2}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1-2}{7}+...\right)$$
$$4\left(2-1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+...\right)=8-4\ln(2)$$
However, the actual answer says $8-8\ln(2)$. Where did the extra multiple of 2 in the log come from???

Rewrite $\frac1{n}=\frac2{2n},$ and then the series might be clearer.

You can't rearrange a series arbitrarily and get the same sum if the series isn't absolute;y convergent.

WTH??? That's so weird!!???

ohhhhhhh, gotcha

@Silver it's called the Riemann Series Theorem.

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{4}{n\left(2n+1\right)}=4\int _0^1\left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\right)\:\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=-4\int _0^1\ln \left(1-x^2\right)\:\mathrm{d}x=-4\left(2\ln \left(2\right)-2\right)$$
$$\therefore \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{4}{n\left(2n+1\right)}=8-8\ln \left(2\right)$$

The series $4\left(1-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{7}+...\right)$ does not converge absolutely.  So (in general) you cannot re-arrange it into
$4\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-2}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1-2}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1-2}{7}+...\right)$.  Indeed, you can rearrange this series to produce any real number as sum.


Does this mean that (for example) the accepted answer is incorrect?

This explains what the OP did wrong.  In fact, the accepted answer is fine.  (Maybe it deserves the explanation of "Tonelli's Theorem" (nonnegative Fubini) to justify $\sum \int = \int \sum$.)

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{n(2 n+1)} 
& =8 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{2 n+1}\right) \\
&=-8 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2 n+1}-\frac{1}{2 n}\right) \\
&=-8\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}-1\right) \\
& =-8(\ln 2-1) \\
&= 8-8 \ln 2 
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!

This is the expression of a personal point of view.
Fot this kind of problems, I prefer to compute the partial sums and later go to the limit.
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{4}{n(2n+1)}=4\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{n}-8\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
$$S_p=4 H_p+4 \left(\psi \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\psi
  \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$ Going from the polygamma function to generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_p=8 (1-\log (2))+4 \left(H_p-H_{p+\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$ Now, using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$H_q=\log (q)+\gamma+\frac{1}{2 q}-\frac{1}{12
   q^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^4}\right)$$ applying it twice and continuing with Taylor series
$$S_p=8 (1-\log (2))-\frac{6}{p}+\frac{15}{2 p^2}-\frac{10}{p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ which shows the limit and much more information.
